# Address book not showing details with new Lion

Tags: macos

I have just downloaded Lion and iCloud and now when I open Address Book from the dock on my desktop, all the names come up but no details????

Comment: May be just an effect of overloaded servers, I had the same issue with Contacts on my iPhone where it took about 6h to update all addresses.

Comment: Are these addresses that were on your system before, or ones you just synced?